Editing Templates in Dhiwise
I am new on dhiwise, I picked a template and would like to add my on text, buttons , input but I cant seem to find the options
I was using android studio but opted to pick dhiwise because my computer is too slow and I thought to build something while I wait to make upgrades. In the android builder dhiwise, I expected it to be similar to android studio where I can pick a view and edit its properties. i tried going to the textviews but its like I can only change id or texview type but not the content or text property. Is there a place that will allow me make changes
